# Has anybody been able to get Python suds to work with Exchange Web Services?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, exchangewebservices, suds

I am trying to be able to call some methods like UpdateItem and have not been successful.  I keep getting the following error:

Exception: imported schema (http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace) at (http://www
.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd), failed

If someone could post some working code that creates a client and successfully calls a method I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you.  I read somewhere that downloading the schema file locally onto my pc could help, but I'm not sure how to implement that in my code either.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib2
import suds
import logging
from suds import WebFault
from suds.client import Client
from suds.client import Factory
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
from logging import getLogger
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import

# cannot access schema through browser
imp = Import('http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client('http:path to wsdl', doctor = d, username='my_username',       
password='my_password')
retVal = client.service.GetServerTimeZones()
print retVal
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use the [suds-ews](https://bitbucket.org/daevaorn/suds-ews) fork.  Also you'll have to implement ntlm authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old, but for people who come here seeking alternatives there's a new wrapper you can try that uses suds - [EWSWrapper_py](http://ewswrapper.lafiel.net/), EWS Wrapper python implementation. It's mainly focused on exchange calendar, but provides good ground for further development. Source hosted on GIT.

At a glance, current features include:

> - Operations on Calendar Events:
>
>   - add,
>   - update,
>   - delete,
>   - list
>   - synch
> - Operations on Tasks:
>
>   - add,
>   - update,
>   - delete,
>   - list
> - Operations of Folders:
>
>   - list
>   - sync